# How to create an instance by using the name of the class of another instance in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am trying to do something that looks something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        print(x + y)

a = Foo(10,20)
b = a.CLASSTYPE(20,30)
```

(Note: I know that there is nothing such as CLASSTYPE)

Is something like this possible? And if it is, how could I implement it in python.
Anything would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are asking how to get the class of an object, no? That's just `type(myobj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get a reference the type of `a`, then call that:

```
b = type(a)(20, 30)
```

There's also `a.__class__`, but you should generally avoid using so-called dunder names (name beginning and ending with a double underscore) directly.